# How to stop execution of selenium scripts that is continued to execute event after the jenkins job is aborted

Tags: windows, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

Issue:
I've started a selenium scripts execution job from the jenkins when few of the selenium scripts are executed i've aborted the job from the jenkins manually. But, the selenium scripts are continued to be running even after i aborted the job

can any one help with the solution to stop the selenium scripts execution

if the job is aborted

Can any one suggest me the windows command to stop the selenium scripts execution that are running continuosly

Comment: In the above scenario we need to stop the execution of the selenium scripts after the corresponding jenkins job is aborted forcefully.Can any one please suggest me the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can go to "**Manage Jenkins**" > "**Script Console**" to run a script on your server to interrupt the hanging thread.

Get all the live threads by running :

```
Thread.getAllStackTraces();
```

You can interupt the thread which is hanged, by running :

```
Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().each() 
{
  t -> if (t.getName()=="THREAD NAME" )
 {   t.interrupt();  }
```

}

Comment: I dont know how to get the Thread name for the job and i want this to be run only when the job is aborted

Answer (score 0):

If your jenkins build isn't aborting,
Check the thread dump http://yourserver/jenkins/threadDump and look for the executor thread in question — they are named after the slave and executor number. That'll normally tell you where the thread is, and often reveals why it's not responding to an interruption.